# How do I install npm dependencies to build a reactjs app using VSTS?

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops

I am trying to build a reactjs using vsts (visual studio team services). I have a very simple pipeline outlined below.   Everytime I run Build it fails.  It fails because it cannot find the node_modules folder.  It seems they are being installed at the wrong directory location.

How can I install the node modules at the correct location? It seems to me that I need to CD into the folder after the `get source` command but I cannot figure out how to do change directory before the `npm install` command is ran.

Here is my pipeline:

- get source
- install dependencies
- build
- zip the build

Like this in vsts:

[image: React Build Pipeline]

The second step Install Dependencies, which reads the package.json file and installs the node_modules, does not place the node_modules in the correct location, this causes my next step, build, to fail.

The build error says this:
[image: The failure on build]

I can run this manually

To run this manually using VS Code and git I run the following commands and it works every time. Here are the commands and the output.

Open working folder:

> git init
>
> git clone [web url to package here]
>
> ls
>
> d-----  8/30/2018 10: 56 AM CairsWebClient
>
> cd CairsWebClient
>
> npm install
>
> npm start

Runs perfect.

Here are the details of the install command in vsts:

[image: content of install command]

I have tried adding the following to the package.json location field. It always fails.
./CairsWebClient - Fail
/CairsWebClient - Fail cannot find C:\CairsWebClient
CairsWebClient - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\1\s\CairsWebClient'

Comment: Is this a hosted agent, or an installed agent running the build?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the folder path of your project's package.json in **Working folder with package.jso**n input box, otherwise, it will uses current process's working folder.